# How to dynamically set a variable name in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, variable

I am looking for a `sh` equivalent of the following (yes, really.)

```
#!/bin/bash

exe1='filepath'
n=1
var=exe${n}
echo ${!var}
```

Where the echo should output `filepath`.
I want to use plain sh.

I have already played around with the code a lot, but I didn't manage to get the output right so far.

I want to achieve an array-like structure, I'd just want to iterate over the variable name for a known number of variables using a loop.

For the array I found [Arrays in a POSIX compliant shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385962/arrays-in-a-posix-compliant-shell) but I'm still looking for the answer to the question for curiosity ;)

Comment: The POSIX shell has arrays! Well, it has _one_ list, the list of positional parameters. Depending on what it is you'd want to do, this may be of use. Note that the code in your question has nothing to do with arrays in `bash`, but about indirection. If you could show a more complete example, we could show how to do the same with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: The question is not about the arrays, so nothing to note here.

Comment: Then why are you even mentioning arrays in the question and [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557361/how-to-dynamically-set-a-variable-name-in-shell-script#comment1035520_557363)?

Comment: Since stackoverflow recommends writing down the motivation. Then I found another way for that, but that doesn't mean I am not interested in exactly what I was asking.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the positional parameters by the way, that makes the code much easier to read!

Comment: Your code (as shown) does not use any lists, so I can't see how using the positional parameters would make it easier to read, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An equivalent `sh` script to what's presented in the question:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

exe1='filepath'
n=1
var=exe$n
eval "echo \"\$$var\""   # or: eval 'echo "$'"$var"'"'
```

The `eval` line will evaluate the given string as a command in the current environment. The given string is `echo \"\$$var\"`, which, after variables have been expanded etc., would become `echo "$exe1"`.  This is passed to `eval` for re-evaluation, and the command prints the string `filepath`.

---

You also mention arrays.  It is true that the POSIX `sh` shell does not have named arrays in the same sense that e.g. `bash` has, but it still has the list of positional parameters.

With it, you can do most things that you'd need to do with a list in the shell.

For example,

```sh
set -- 'filepath1' 'filepath2' 'filepath3'

for name in "$@"; do    # or: for name do
    echo "$name"
done
```

which is the same as just

```sh
for name in 'filepath1' 'filepath2' 'filepath3'
do
    echo "$name"
done
```

Since I'm usure of what it is you're trying to achieve, I can't come up with a more interesting example. But here you have an array-like structure that you iterate over. Why you'd want to iterate over names of variables is still not clear.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the answer that I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to iterate over a number of files (implied from `exe1=filepath` in example) does a simple for loop work?

`final_file` is the variable holding the last file which matches the file_pattern - replicating bash's `${!var}` (last argument referencing).

```
  #/bin/sh
  final_file=''
  file_pattern='*.txt'
  for f in $file_pattern
  do
      echo $f
      final_file=$f
  done
  echo $final_file
```

Comment: huh? this doesn't seem to respond at all to my question...? No, patterns won't do here, file paths are arbitrary.

Comment: ok, why not arbitrary `file_pattern="f1.txt a.out arbitrary.c README"` ?